# Draw point on google map

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, intersection, wfs-t

i try to add google map on my own wms and wfs layer. everything works but when i create point, i intersect point geometry and my geojson data. So without googlemap it was run. But when add google map, points cordinates will be different and intersect result is wrong.you can see picture what i said. when i click on africa, intersect results is correct but i must click on my overlays layers.

http://i.hizliresim.com/xVyDJj.png

WFS_LAYER

```
 wfs_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Point Layer",
        {

            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: 10, // sized according to type attribute
                    fillColor: "#00FFFF",
                    strokeColor: "#33CCCC",
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    graphicZIndex: 1
                }),
            }),

            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],

            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                version: version,//1.1.0
                // loading data through localhost url path
                url: wfsUrl,
                featureNS: featureNS,
                visibility: true,
                // layer name
                featureType: featureType,
                // geometry column name
                srsName: "EPSG:900913",
                geometryName: geometryName,
                schema: schema,

            })
        });
```

point intersect :

```
 function mahalleBul(request) {

            var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                internalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            });
            var getMahalle = geojson_format.read(request.responseText);
            if (getMahalle.length > 0) {
                mahalleadi = getMahalle[0].attributes.ADI;
                mahallegisID = getMahalle[0].attributes.GIS_ID;
            }
}
 var request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
            url: rootURL + "ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Kaski:ADRES_MAHALLE&outputFormat=json&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom," + feature.geometry + ")",


            callback: mahalleBul
        });
```

Comment: epsg projection 2322 - ed50 / tm36 my epsg. i have to transform my point geometry which i click

Comment: for example on this map i got point 33 lat 41 long but in my database there is no this cordinates because my database epsg 2322